# Using Preferences API to save path?

Tags: java, windows, preferences, regedit

I'm trying use Preferences API to save a path to file in regedit. It is works but the value of path is not saved correctly.

I'm trying this.

```
public class ImageLogoPreference {

    private final String path = "configs";        
    private Preferences node;

    public ImageLogoPreference(){        
        node = Preferences.userRoot().node(path);
    }

    public void setImageLogo(){                
        node.put("logo", "\\IguanaSistemas\\IguanaFight\\imagens\\logo.png");
    }

    public String getImageLogo(){
        String logo = node.get("logo", "image");
        return logo;
    }    

}
```

At register save this: `///Iguana/Sistemas///Iguana/Fight//imagens//logo.png`

[image]
Any idea ?

Comment: The API is auto formatting the value based on it's requirements, same thing happens to `Properties` when they are saved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't matter.

Just get it in your Java program. You don't have a problem.

```
    Preferences node =  Preferences.userRoot().node("config");
    //node.put("logo", "\\IguanaSistemas\\IguanaFight\\imagens\\logo.png");
    String s = node.get("logo", "blah");
    System.out.println(s);
```

Prints the correct string.